# Memory module bidirectional data is unknown

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to implement this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
module memory 
# (
    parameter AWIDTH = 5,
    parameter DWIDTH = 8
  )
  (
    input wire [AWIDTH-1:0] addr,
    input wire clk, wr, rd,
    inout wire [DWIDTH-1:0] data
  );
    reg [DWIDTH-1:0] mem [AWIDTH-1:0];

    assign data = rd ? mem[addr] : {DWIDTH{1'bz}};

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (wr)
            mem[addr] <= data;
    end
endmodule
```

Here is the result:

> Loading snapshot worklib.memory_test:v .................... Done
> xcelium> source /tools/cdnc/xcelium/current/tools/xcelium/files/xmsimrc
> xcelium> run
> Writing addr=00000 data=11111111
> Writing addr=11111 data=00000000
> Reading addr=00000 data=11111111
> At time 40 addr=00000 data=11111111
> Reading addr=11111 data=00000000
> TEST FAILED
> At time 50 addr=11111 data=xxxxxxxx
> data should be 00000000
> Simulation complete via $finish(1) at time 50 NS + 0
> ./memory_test.v:35       $finish;
> xcelium> exit
> TOOL:   xrun(64)        19.09-s010: Exiting on May 23, 2021 at 03:45:50 IDT  (total: 00:00:01)

It doesn't save my data (x is uninitialized).
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the test bench code:

```
module memory_test;

  localparam integer AWIDTH=5;
  localparam integer DWIDTH=8;

  reg               clk   ;
  reg               wr    ;
  reg               rd    ;
  reg  [AWIDTH-1:0] addr  ;
  wire [DWIDTH-1:0] data  ;
  reg  [DWIDTH-1:0] rdata ;

  assign data=rdata;

  memory
  #(
    .AWIDTH ( AWIDTH ),
    .DWIDTH ( DWIDTH ) 
   )
  memory_inst
   (
    .clk  ( clk  ),
    .wr   ( wr   ),
    .rd   ( rd   ),
    .addr ( addr ),
    .data ( data ) 
   );

  task expect;
    input [DWIDTH-1:0] exp_data;
    if (data !== exp_data) begin
      $display("TEST FAILED");
      $display("At time %0d addr=%b data=%b", $time, addr, data);
      $display("data should be %b", exp_data);
      $finish;
    end
   else begin 
      $display("At time %0d addr=%b data=%b", $time, addr, data);
   end 
  endtask

  initial repeat (67) begin #5 clk=1; #5 clk=0; end

  initial @(negedge clk) begin : TEST
    reg [AWIDTH-1:0] addr;
    reg [DWIDTH-1:0] data;
    addr=0; data=-1;
    $display("Writing addr=%b data=%b",addr,data);
    wr=1; rd=0; memory_test.addr=addr; rdata=data; @(negedge clk);
    addr=-1; data=0;
    $display("Writing addr=%b data=%b",addr,data);
    wr=1; rd=0; memory_test.addr=addr; rdata=data; @(negedge clk);
    addr=0; data=-1;
    $display("Reading addr=%b data=%b",addr,data);
    wr=0; rd=1; memory_test.addr=addr; rdata='bz; @(negedge clk) expect(data);
    addr=-1; data=0;
    $display("Reading addr=%b data=%b",addr,data);
    wr=0; rd=1; memory_test.addr=addr; rdata='bz; @(negedge clk) expect(data);
    $display("Writing ascending data to   descending addresses");
    addr=-1; data=0;
    while ( addr ) begin
      wr=1; rd=0; memory_test.addr=addr; rdata=data; @(negedge clk);
      addr=addr-1;
      data=data+1;
    end
    $display("Reading ascending data from descending addresses");
    addr=-1; data=0;
    while ( addr ) begin
      wr=0; rd=1; memory_test.addr=addr; rdata='bz; @(negedge clk) expect(data);
      addr=addr-1;
      data=data+1;
    end
    $display("TEST PASSED");
    $finish;
  end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

You created `mem` using

```systemverilog
reg [DWIDTH-1:0] mem [AWIDTH-1:0];
```

So you have `mem` with `5` rows and then you send address `'h 1f` (row `32` counting from 1) which is out of your `mem`.
To fix this problem you have to create `mem` with `32` rows. I suggest power operator. Example `mem` with `32` rows:

```systemverilog
reg [DWIDTH-1:0] mem [2**AWIDTH-1:0];
```